# How to replace a value in msha file using powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am having a .msha file. Following is the content of the file.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Class References</title>
</head>
<body class="vendor-book">
    <div class="details">
        <span class="vendor">Pearson</span>
        <span class="locale">en-us</span>
        <span class="product">Class References</span>
        <span class="name">Class References</span>
    </div>
    <div class="package-list">
        <div class="package">
            <!-- NOTE: The "name" span value cannot contain any periods! -->
            <span class="name">ClassReference</span>
            <a class="current-link" href="ClassReference.mshc">ClassReference.mshc</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have to replace the following tag

```
<a class="current-link" href="ClassReference.mshc">ClassReference.mshc</a>
```

as follows

```
<a class="current-link" href="ClassReference.mshc.cab">ClassReference.mshc</a>
```

How to do it using powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
${C:\test\test.msha} =  ${C:\test\test.msha} -replace 'href="ClassReference\.mshc"','href="ClassReference.mshc.cab"'
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to read the file as XML and replace the tag. The following will work only when the tags are always in the same format.

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content C:\script\test.hta)
$xml.html.body.div[1].div.a.href = "ClassReference.mshc.cab"
$xml.html.body.div[1].div.a.href
$xml.InnerXml.ToString() | Out-File .\test.hta
```

HTH

Comment: It loses formatting when i use this suggestion. All the lines in msha file is being displayed as one line. Whether out-file does some thing with formatting?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by reading the file's contents as text and do a simple *search & replace* using the `-replace` [string operator](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/archive/2009/03/30/chapter-13-text-and-regular-expressions.aspx#string-operators) in PowerShell:

```
(Get-Content MyFile.hta) -replace "href=`"ClassReference.mshc`"", "href=`"ClassReference.mshc.cab`"" `
    | Set-Content MyFile.hta
```